# How to change height div on window resize?

Tags: jquery, window, height

I have a div on my website that should be the height of the window.
This is what i got:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
});
```

However, it does not automatically change when the window is resized? Does any body know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't deal with this problem with CSS? JS solutions would be at best choppy on "some" browsers (no need to name the beast I suppose)...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53hoq9w7/

Answer (score 54):

You also need to do that in `resize` event, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var bodyheight = $(this).height();
        $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: I think the world would be a better place if this solution was edited so that the `ready` and `resize` calls shared a single function, rather than using duplicated code. People tend to copy-paste javascript code pretty blindly: why not show them the best practice?

Comment: +1 for resize event.  I was having a similar problem and this helped out nicely.  I will be following aaaidan's advice though and throwing this in a single function.

Comment: In resize handler you can not use `$(document)` node. I'd suggest using `$(this)` selector since this is being resized.

Answer (score 7):

Just to show the DRY-up suggested in the comment on the accepted answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  body_sizer();
  $(window).resize(body_sizer);
});
function body_sizer() {
  var bodyheight = $(window).height();
  $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
}
```

And of course this is kind of silly since it is something that could be done with CSS more simply.  But if there were a calculation involved that would be a different story.  Eg this example which makes a div fill the bottom of the window, minus a little fudgefactor.

```
$(function(){
  resize_main_pane();
  $(window).resize(resize_main_pane);
});
function resize_main_pane() {
  var offset = $('#main_scroller').offset(),
  remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - offset.top - 50);
  $('#main_scroller').height(remaining_height);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to have the HTML5 doctype in the HTML file.  Decreasing window size does not work with these methods unless you add this to the top of the HTML file: `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 5):

Some clarification on this, in order for the window to resize correct after each callback you must clarify which height to retrieve.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(window).resize(function() {
          var bodyheight = $(window).height();
          $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
       }); 
    });
```

Otherwise, from my experience, the height will keep increasing now matter how you resize the window.  This will take the height of the current window.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said make sure you extract the event handler code into a separate function and call it from `ready` and `resize` event handlers. That way if you add some more code or need to bind it to other events you will have only one place where to change code logic.

Comment: What you should also do in that case is make sure you set the height in the correct place.  Don't make a mistake I once did, and set the height of the two div's that comprised my page, then set the width of one of the columns - which changed the height, resulting in an overflow situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `resize` event.

This should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
}); });
```

Comment: You don't need the resize event handler within your $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

     $(window).on("resize",function() {

          var bodyheight = $(document).height();

          $("#sidebar").height(bodyheight);
     });

});
```