# css display block height change in browser window

Tags: html, css

i will describe my problem with an example: lets say we draw a block with css, we can see the effect when dragging the browser window horizontally the block's width will change until it reaches its minimum width. Now I want it to do same with the block's height its not working which is im having a problem with. Any help?

Here is my example code:

```
#block {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    background-color: rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.15);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bab9b9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bab9b9; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bab9b9; /* Safari, Chrome */
}
```

Comment: Check this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758651/how-to-change-height-div-on-window-resize

Answer (score 1):

Well you can add

```
padding-top:50%
```

to your block css and the height changes as you adjust the width of your browser. I only tested this on FF so I dunno if this works on other browsers or not and I am not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question. You haven't set any `min-width` on your block. What are you trying to achieve - a block that is 100% height of the window?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no because I think you mean the change of the margin-left and -right. 
With the height this won't work like expected because the height ist often higher than the window-height.

Maybe it could work if you have a limited height but I never tried this out. And I don't think  `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;` has the same effect as `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

So... as suggested... if you want this effect then use JS instead