# Creating resizable website with lack of CSS skills - CSS shapes

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-shapes

This is my first question here, so please point out any of mistakes that I made. 
I was obliged to create a web page that looks like a flag of a team. I've managed to do such, but only with fixed size of elements :[image] 
On other resolutions it just doesn't fit the screen.
Code:
 html

```
<div id="centered">
    <div id="triangle-down"></div>
    <div id="triangle-right"></div>
    <div id="triangle-left"></div>
    <div id="triangle-up"></div>
    <div id="diamond-narrow"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
    #centered {
        position:relative; clear:left;
        height:766px; width:1245;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#fff;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #triangle-up {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 281px;
        margin-top: 555px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 341px solid transparent;
        border-right: 341px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 211px solid #3b5998;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #triangle-down {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 281px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 341px solid transparent;
        border-right: 341px solid transparent;
        border-top: 211px solid #3b5998;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #triangle-left {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 902px;
        margin-top: 171px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 211px solid transparent;
        border-right: 343px solid #3b5998;
        border-bottom: 211px solid transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #triangle-right {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 171px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 211px solid transparent;
        border-left: 343px solid #3b5998;
        border-bottom: 211px solid transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #diamond-narrow {
        margin-left: 342px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 280px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 173px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top: -70px;
}

    #diamond-narrow:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: -280px; top: 173px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 280px solid transparent;
        border-top: 173px solid red;
    }
```

Here's a jsfiddle of my flag: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/XDLYF/1/) 
As you can see I am using css shapes to draw triangles and a diamond. My questions are:
How can I make that flag (web page) to fit different screen resolutions? How to present width and height of my shapes in percentages?
As I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages), eg. border-left can not have a value in %.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @joe_coolish, I managed to make that web page resizable. However, I got one more problem.
Here's my html:

```
<table width="100%" style="height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
        <td id="centered" bgcolor="white">
            <div id="main"/>
        </td>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td width="10%" height="10%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Changes to Joe's code:

```
var main = $('#main');

function update() {

var height = $('#centered').height();
var width = $('#centered').width();

...

$('#centered').resize(function () {
update();
});
```

Now when I load my page, this happens: [image: before inspecting]
I have to inspect some element to work it properly. Why?

Comment: Sometimes an image is the right way to go.

Comment: Please do not link to your web site - it will become irrelevant to your question once it changes, reducing its value to other users.

Comment: You can use jquery if you want the size to adjust to the window size. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758651/how-to-change-height-div-on-window-resize

Comment: Use ems, and size the containing div?

Comment: You could use SVG or HTML canvas to create your image. It wouldn't work in all browser/OS combinations, but neither does your current solution.

Comment: what about CSS3 `transform:rotate` ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I see that there are various ways to do that. Right now I'm going to try some.

Comment: Are you sure that's a flag? It looks like it's on the floor = a rug.

Comment: :D I was not a designer :D It is a basketball team, and that "floor" is supposed to be a basketball court. Or basketball floor, don't know how to call it.

Comment: Could you update your jsfiddle with the new edits?  I'll get it to full screen for you :)

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to answer your chat question: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Ew4/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also go with SVG.

More math, but it does work pretty well.  Just attach to the `$(window).resize()` event and then update the triangles.  Here is my first attempt:

```
var main = $('#main');

function update() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();

    var height10 = height / 5
    var heightMinus10 = height - height10;
    var width10 = width / 5
    var widthMinus10 = width - width10;

    var height2 = height / 2;
    var width2 = width / 2;
    var width3 = width2 - width10;
    var height3 = height2 - height10;
    var width3x2 = width2 + width10;
    var height3x2 = height2 + height10;

    var points1 = '0,' + height10 + ' 0,' + heightMinus10 + ' ' + width3 + ',' + height2;
    var points2 = width10 + ',0 ' + widthMinus10 + ',0 ' + width2 + ',' + height3;
    var points3 = width + ',' + height10 + ' '+width+',' + heightMinus10 + ' ' + width3x2 + ',' + height2;
    var points4 = width10 + ','+height + ' ' + widthMinus10 + ','+height+' ' + width2 + ',' + height3x2;
    var points5 = width3 + ',' + height2 + ' '+width2+',' + height3 + ' ' + width3x2 + ',' + height2 + ' ' + width2 + ',' + height3x2;

    var svg1 = '<svg height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '">'+
        '<polygon points="' + points1 + '" style="fill:blue" />'+
        '<polygon points="' + points2 + '" style="fill:blue" />'+
        '<polygon points="' + points3 + '" style="fill:blue" />'+
        '<polygon points="' + points4 + '" style="fill:blue" />'+
        '<polygon points="' + points5 + '" style="fill:red" />'+
        '</svg>';

    main.empty();
    main.append($(svg1));
}

update();

$(window).resize(function () {
    update();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ePt62/

Comment: This is awesome. Can you see my edit? However, you helped me a lot and solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw your update.  If you update the JSFiddle, I'll work on it and update mine accordingly

Comment: More or less it is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Ew4/ But as I said, in browser, if I inspect any element, the polygons resize to the white field and everything is good.

Comment: It is great, but I don't know why main div doesn't fill the centered div. I mean, flag is matched horizontally, but not vertically.  EDIT : this helps : `<td id="centered" bgcolor="white" width="80%" height="80%">`

Comment: Yeah, it's because the table rows are set to 10%.  Tables are kinda strange like that.  Glad I could help!  The issue was that `main` needed to be emptied before the height was calculated, and the resize event needed to be attached to window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44823/discussion-between-macfij-and-joe-coolish)

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to do this, is to write different rules for different screen sizes.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px){
  // your current sizes, anywhere you use px values really, can go here
}


@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
  // smaller sizes that give similar results can go here
}
```

Repeat the process for every device you target, until you have a good one for each resolution.

Note that the flag will only have as many sizes as you specify using these "break points".

It may not seem like the cleverest solution, but it will be very reliable.

it's possible to do css that will work at any size, but that involves the code getting a bit fancy, and learning the techniques might take you longer than doing it the simple way.

One final note: 1245px is very big for a default size. A lot of users will be using narrower displays than that.