# how can i make the height of a website resize when browserwindow resizes?

Tags: html, css, browser, window

I need to make my webpage so that the height of containers resizes when I scale the browser window smaller or bigger. I already have the width resizes automatically but with the height I am struggling.

this is my script so far:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Opdracht4.css">
</head>   
<body>
    <div class="allcontainers"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.allcontainers
{
background-color: #555;
width: 90%;
height: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You will have to get the height to 100% on `html` & `body` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

if you always want a 50% height of the window's height then you can use `height: 50vh;`

Comment: well. that did the trick for me. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You welcome. I suggest you also try Ruddy's suggestion adding a 100% height to all the parent elements ( if you want full height ), in IE it will maybe be an issue if you do not. Also it is not always practical to use 'vh' it all depends of what are you trying to accomplish.. Good Luck!

Comment: i am just messing around with different sized divs and trying to adapt them to resize of browser and have them stand in the middle. but this will work for that so

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this using CSS only. I'd suggest adding js listener that resets the css height value everytime the browser window is resized. Have a look at
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758651/how-to-change-height-div-on-window-resize)

Comment: i am no good at js. so i will fly that plane away. i am currently busy learning html and css and i know it can be solved with css so.

Comment: In his case height: 50% in class .allcontainers doesn't mean 50% of browser window. I think that's why he is having the problem

Answer (score 0):

In order for your example to work, you need to add to your css:
html, body {
height: 100%
}

Remember that your element will have 50% (in your case) of the height of its parent (body). And the body will have 100% height of its parent (html). You always have to give the parents a height, so that the element you target can relate to that.

Also, if you want your element to have a true 50% height, add html, body {
margin:0} - to reset the browser default.