# If window height < change css

Tags: javascript, css

I need to adjust the top absolute position of a div on page load, depending on browser height. But my code does not work, despite I got parts of it together from several stackoverflow posts. But I am not a programmer though. The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /* place title higher for small screen */
window_size = $(window).height();
$(window).load(function() {
if(window_size < 800) {
     $('#frontbildtitle').css('top': 100);
     }
});
</script>
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Use media queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758651/how-to-change-height-div-on-window-resize

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with pure CSS using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). eg:

```
.frontbildtitle {
  top:50px;
}

@media screen and (min-height:600px){
  .frontbildtitle {
    top:100px;
  }
}
```

Also, notice i've used a class name for `frontbildtitle` instead of an ID. Classes are better for CSS performance. ID's are better for JS performance.

Comment: This is the correct approach to maintain clear separation of concerns

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I did not think of media queries, this did it indeed. Except it needed to be max-height, not min-height.

Comment: @thomahawk Actually, ideally, the CSS should use a mobile-first approach - min-height is best for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /* place title higher for small screen */
    window_size = $(window).height();
    $(window).load(function() {
    if(window_size < 800) {
        $('#frontbildtitle').css('top', 100);
    }
});
</script>
```

Should work

EDIT :

You can use .css method in two ways :

- `$("#myId").css("color", "red")`, as arguments in a JS function where the first one is the key and the second one the value (You can only modify one thing this way)
- `$("#myId").css({color:"red"})` as an object where you can modify as values as you want

A richer example :

```
var myColor = "red";
$("#myId").css({
    color : myColor,
    "text-align": "center"
});
```

Take care to quote keys with "-", or it will throw an error

All details at [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What was the problem? What did you change? Why should that fix it?

Comment: You're right, I changed ":" with "," on css method call

Comment: — I suggest you edit that into the answer then. Even better if you explain what happens when the `:` is incorrectly used.